# Using R: how to animate multiple 3D objects in single rgl canvas?

Tags: r, animation, 3d, mesh, rgl

I have data where a participant had positional data on each hand:

left:
right:

positional data has

```
pos.x
pos.y
pos.z
```

at some time `t`

The initial question was about importing OBJ to work with RGL:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46626767/revisions

I have figured that part out.  I have written functions to improve `rgl` mesh framework for open-source OBJ files.

I placed the required functions online:  https://gist.github.com/MonteShaffer/d142210cddf346c86aeab1ea2d1d7e9d

The positional data should be captured on a wrist watch, so I want to be able to show two or more 3D data objects and animate each independently based on positional/time data.

That is, treat the hand like a rigid object with the wrist-watch region moving appropriately.

I placed the hand.OBJ file online:  https://gist.github.com/MonteShaffer/6c0057b1431364caf120220db77dde4b

I am aware of basic graphing, updating, spinning:

```
library(rgl)

mymesh = buildBasicMeshFromOBJ(parseFileOBJ("hand.OBJ"));

open3d()
shade3d(mymesh, col = "pink")
par3d(userMatrix = rotate3d(par3d("userMatrix"), 0.1, 1,0,0))
play3d(spin3d(axis = c(1, 0, 0)))
```

My goal is to plot multiple objects on the same rgl canvas.

e.g.,

```
righthand = mymesh
lefthand = mymesh

head = buildBasicMeshFromOBJ(parseFileOBJ("head.obj"));
```

and have each element move independently as an animation over time based on positional/time data for each element.  For now the head stays still, but each hand moves based on the rigid idea with the position representing the wrist.

It would be a bonus that the mouse drag could still occur (to change 3D views around the hands and head) while the animation is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can move objects within the scene by using a function like `rotate3d`.  Despite its name, it allows for quite general kinds of movement:  see the help page.

So instead of using `par3d` to move things, move the objects themselves.

`rgl` doesn't provide a way to modify objects that are already in the scene (though the WebGL display of `rgl` objects does...), so the basic idea is the following:

- Plot the object, and save the ids (e.g. `ids <- shade3d(mymesh)`)
- Then, in a loop:

  - Turn off updates (using `par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE)`)
  - Delete the object (e.g. `rgl.pop(id=ids)`)
  - Move and replot the object
  - Turn on updates.

The `play3d` function provides a framework to automate this, but you don't need to use it.  For example, this plots two icosahedra and randomly rotates them independently:

```
orig1 <- icosahedron3d()
id1 <- shade3d(orig1, col = "green")
orig2 <- translate3d(orig1, 4, 0, 0)
id2 <- shade3d(orig2, col = "blue")

repeat {
  orig1 <- rotate3d(orig1, 0.01, rnorm(1, 1), rnorm(1), rnorm(1))
  orig2 <- rotate3d(orig2, 0.05, rnorm(1, -1), rnorm(1), rnorm(1))
  par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)
  rgl.pop(id = c(id1, id2))
  id1 <- shade3d(orig1, col = "green")
  id2 <- shade3d(orig2, col = "blue")
  par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE)
}
```

Another way to do this is to set up two separate subscenes.  Then each
can be controlled by its own `par3d()` setting.  For example,

```
icos <- icosahedron3d()
ids <- mfrow3d(1,2)
shade3d(icos, col = "red")
next3d()
shade3d(icos, col = "green")
```

Now each of the icosahedra can be manipulated independently with the mouse.  If you want to do it with `par3d`, use something like `par3d(..., subscene = ids[1])` to affect the left pane, `par3d(..., subscene = ids[2])` for the right pane.

Comment: very instructive! Thank you. Why the last line within the repeat block par3d(skipRedraw=FALSE)? What is its purpose?

Comment: A few lines up `skipRedraw` was set to `TRUE`.  This stops `rgl` from refreshing the display.  When it is set back to the default `skipRedraw=FALSE`, all of the changes in the intervening lines will appear at once.  This stops flickering as multiple changes are made.